# Saving transparent PNG as JPEG on white background

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Say I have an BGRA image as `numpy` array that looks pretty much like this:

```
[[[233 228 230   128]
  [233 228 230   128]
  [233 228 230   0]
  ...
  [164 160 159   65]
  [199 197 196   65]
  [255 255 254   120]]
```

That looks pretty straightforward - three colour channels + one alpha that controls transparency of pixels. Saving that numpy array in a PNG format results in an image that is semi-transparent as it should be.

However, when saving it as JPEG, the alpha channel is dropped completely and the all of the pixels are fully opaque.

As JPEG does not support alpha-transparency, I would like my semi-transparent image (the numpy array above) to be saved on a white background instead. That way, it would appear as if the pixels would still be semi-transparent.

How can I overlay the semi-transparent numpy array on a fully white background? I am using mainly numpy and OpenCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking more for gradated alpha-blending than the simpler alpha-thresholding that Fred's answer nicely demonstrates.

I made a sample image with an alpha gradient in the middle for test purposes. Here it is as a normal image and composited over a checkerboard to show the transparency like Photoshop does:

[image]

[image]

To do alpha blending you use the formula:

```
result = alpha * Foreground + (1-alpha)*Background
```

where the values are all floats scaled on the range 0..1

---

The code for blending over black and then white background follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, including gradient alpha layer
im = cv2.imread('GradientAlpha.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Separate BGR channels from A, make everything float in range 0..1
BGR = im[...,0:3].astype(np.float)/255
A   = im[...,3].astype(np.float)/255

# First, composite image over black background using:
# result = alpha * Foreground + (1-alpha)*Background
bg  = np.zeros_like(BGR).astype(np.float)     # black background
fg  = A[...,np.newaxis]*BGR                   # new alpha-scaled foreground
bg = (1-A[...,np.newaxis])*bg                 # new alpha-scaled background
res = cv2.add(fg, bg)                         # sum of the parts
res = (res*255).astype(np.uint8)              # scaled back up
cv2.imwrite('OverBlack.png', res)

# Now, composite image over white background
bg  = np.zeros_like(BGR).astype(np.float)+1   # white background
fg  = A[...,np.newaxis]*BGR                   # new alpha-scaled foreground
bg = (1-A[...,np.newaxis])*bg                 # new alpha-scaled background
res = cv2.add(fg, bg)                         # sum of the parts
res = (res*255).astype(np.uint8)              # scaled back up
cv2.imwrite('OverWhite.png', res)
```

That gives this over black:

[image]

And this over white:

[image]

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, OpenCV, alpha, alpha blending, alpha compositing, overlay.

Comment: how can I grant you my bounty for your excellent answer to the other question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874129/alpha-blending-two-images-with-opencv-and-or-numpy

Comment: @Pono It's ok, I am not too worried by points - I just enjoy helping folk. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Python OpenCV Numpy, you can separate the alpha channel from the image. So if imgA is the image with alpha channel. Then separate the rgb image (img) and the alpha channel (alpha)

```
img = imgA[:,:,0:3]
alpha = imgA[:,:,3]
```

Then set the color of img to white where the alpha is black

```
img[alpha == 0] = (255,255,255)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this does not work as intended. It only replaces *fully transparent* pixels with white colour. What about alpha values like 127 (semi-transparent)? I am looking for a solution that would blend perfectly semi-transparent PNG onto a white canvas.

Comment: Your question was not that clear. Do you want the semi-transparent pixels to be fully white? If not, what color should they be -- proportionally gray?