# how to put transparent image to another image using PIL without .paste() class

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm newbie in PIL so for me it's hard to understand how I can do it, somebody helps me with it. In code, I only take two pictures and resized a transparent one. Now I don't know what to do next to paste it without .paste() class

```
def get_web_image (url):
    img_data = requests.get(url).content
    with open('picture1(bg)_1200x800.png', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    return img_data


def paste_image (source, destination, x, y, omit_color="None"):
    im = Image.open(source)
    pixels_newpaste = []
    newsize = (200, 200)
    im = im.resize(newsize)
    im.save('picture2(done).png')
    im.show()



paste_image ('picture2(transparent)_840x841.png', main_image, 1, 1)
main_pic()
#my_img_object = get_web_image ('https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/Baseball-Wallpapers/Baseball-Wallpapers-015.jpg')
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to make it using .getpixel(), but as I understand it requires only to draw in one color. So please help me to make this function

Comment: What's the problem with using `paste()` please? What's the result supposed to look like please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell it's a quiz, so in requirements said that you can't use paste()
put the second picture in some part of the first picture, for example in the middle. 
I'm learning this framework now, so you can give me some hint, or explain the algorithm, code I can do by myself

Comment: Ugh! You could iterate over all pixels, and at each location get the pixel from both the background and the foreground image. If the foreground image is opaque, overwrite that pixel in the background image with the value from the foreground image. Make a cup if tea while it runs  Or use Numpy... https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035996/2836621

Comment: @Mark Setchell Thanks a lot, I'll try and write soon about the result

Comment: Actually, thinking a little more, you don't need to get the background pixel if you build your output image on top of your background image. Just iterate over the pixels getting the foreground pixel at each location and if the foreground is opaque overwrite the background pixel with the RGB value of the foreground pixel. Otherwise allow the existing background pixel to remain unmodified.

Comment: tried to make it and stuck, don't know how to make it((@Mark Setchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version using these two images which are suitably resized and also partially transparent:

[image]

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open pitcher and pitch images
bg = Image.open('pitch.jpg')
fg = Image.open('pitcher.png').convert('RGBA')
w, h = fg.width, fg.height

# Iterate over rows and columns
for y in range(h):
   for x in range(w):
      # Get components of foreground pixel
      r, g, b, a = fg.getpixel((x,y))
      # If foreground is opaque, overwrite background with foreground
      if a>128:
          bg.putpixel((x,y), (r,g,b))

# Save result    
bg.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: strange, your code gives me mistake:
`File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    r, g, b, a = fg.getpixel((x,y))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)`

Comment: That's because you have used a JPEG (which doesn't support transparency/alpha) as the foreground, so it only has 3 channels (i.e. RGB) rather than 4 channels (i.e. RGBA). That's why I made and shared a PNG with alpha/transparency.

Comment: tried like with your images pitch.jpg, second pitcher.png

`File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    if a > 128:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: Hold on a moment. StackOverflow seems to be converting my PNG to JPEG for some reason...

Comment: I don't know what was happening but StackOverflow kept converting my PNG to JPEG which I have never seen before. I changed a line of code to make sure the paletted version I have now uploaded becomes RGBA.

Comment: tried it and now it gives error: `File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    bg.putpixel((x,y), (r,g,b))
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1737, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
IndexError: image index out of range`

Comment: Find out what's wrong, thanks for help. You did a great job!